# Returning a set value where there is no data

Tags: php, mysql, return

I have report which shows the the products on sale, and the total weight of each product ordered. Here is a markup of the code to show the total weight:

```
$weightsql = 'select op.products_name, sum(op.products_quantity * p.products_weight) as weightsum from ' . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . ' op left join ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p on op.products_id = p.products_id where op.products_id =  '.$pro['products_id'];
$weightq = tep_db_query( $weightsql );
while ($weight = tep_db_fetch_array( $weightq )){
if($category_parent_id != 0)$list_items[] = $weight['weightsum'];
}
```

It returns values for the products ordered, but for the unordered products, it stays blank, which is very confusing. How would I return 0.00 for the unordered products (the products not pulled from the query).

Example:

```
 Product Name         |             Total Weight
                      |
 Jelly Beans          |             25.00
 Soft Candy           |                              This product has not been ordered, needs to show 0.00
 Bubblegum            |             10.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.

```
coalesce( sum(op.products_quantity * p.products_weight), 0 )
```

Also, change `left join` to `right join` because in your query `product` is on right of `order`.

This will replace Null value to `0`.

**Edited** Due OP Comment. You can add new column with desired style:

```
select 
   op.products_name, 
   coalesce( sum(op.products_quantity * p.products_weight), 0 ) as weightsum,
   case when sum(op.products_quantity * p.products_weight) is NULL then 'Normal' 
        else 'Bold' end
   as stype
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, will accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: If I wanted to make the true value bold, and the null value as normal, to recognise the sold products, how would that be done?

Comment: answered in post. @user1879415, next time write a new post for a new question, don't change question requirements.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about your problem: if you want all rows from `TABLE_PRODUCTS`, with matching rows (if any exist) from the `TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS`, you would need `RIGHT JOIN` rather than a `LEFT JOIN` in your query.

However, I prefer to use a `LEFT JOIN` wherever possible, so I would re-order the tables in the query

<snip>

```
... from ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p left join ' . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . ' op ...
```

</snip>

That will fix the problem, if your problem is that you aren't getting the rows you expect.

---

The other issue is dealing with the NULL values returned from the rows returned by the OUTER JOIN.  The quick answer there is to wrap those expressions in an `IFNULL` function to return a 0 (or 0.00, if you need decimal type)

<snip>

```
... IFNULL( sum(op.products_quantity * p.products_weight) ,0.0) as ...
```

or

```
... sum( IFNULL(op.products_quantity,0.0) * IFNULL(p.products_weight, 0.0) ) as
```

</snip>

---

**Q: If I wanted to make the true value bold, and the null value as normal, to recognise the sold products, how would that be done?**

**A:**

I expect you would need to include appropriate **<b>** and **</b>** tags in the generated HTML. (We don't normally return those types of markup tags from a database query, since a lot of the markup is usually handled by CSS.)

From the database, you could include an expression in your SELECT list, to let you know if a matching row was found in the TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCT table or not, something like this:

```
  IF(op.products_id IS NULL,0,1) AS is_ordered
```

That would return to you a 0 if no a matching `products_id` was found in the TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCT table, otherwise it would return a 1.

You could then could use this value to make the determination of what style or markup should be applied to whichever element you needed to make bold.

Comment: If I wanted to make the true value bold, and the null value as normal, to recognise the sold products, how would that be done?